# Azure Devops user access to repos

Tags: github, azure-devops

Similar to Github Cloud is there a way in Azure Devops to create internal repos wherein multiple users can have access to some repos which have certain documents without adding them as users or groups to such repos? If we make RepoA as internal it should be available to all users under an org without specifically adding them.

Comment: Hi, have you checked and tested my answer to see if it works?

Comment: @RoyWang-MSFT this works but my question was different. How can we make a repository internal in ADO where instead of giving access to users to a repo still they may be able to access the repo cos the repo has been created with internal type? In Github Enterprise, we have this option of creating internal repos.

Comment: Hi, on your question, different from Github situation, as the previous explanation, in ADO, without adding users into your org, the users cannot access to the repo you created unless it's a public project. And in Github, the prerequisite for users to access the Internal repositories is that the users are already all added as enterprise members. https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/about-repositories#about-repository-visibility

Comment: Hi, does my answer helps on your concern?

Comment: Yes thanks @RoyWang-MSFT for your response. But this does not resolve my issue as the Github feature of internal repo is what I am looking for. I will raise this with ADO support team.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure DevOps, for public projects, any user can get access your public project and check Git repo without signing in or added as a user in your org. You can also refer to this doc: [Make your private project public - Azure DevOps Services Public Project | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/make-project-public?view=azure-devops) .

If for private projects in Azure DevOps, firstly, users must be granted access to the specified private project also as Basic access level in your org via navigating to Organization Settings -> Users -> Select the specified user -> Manage user to set users' access level.

Users be with Stakeholder access level, they will not be able to use Azure Repos for your private project.

Otherwise, to set permissions for a specific repository or some specific users, navigating to Project Settings -> Repositories -> Security to manage the permissions.

[image]
You can also refer to: [About access levels - Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops) | [Microsoft Learn and Set Git repository permissions - Azure Repos | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-git-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops)